# Google Sheet Filter View regexmatch custom formula

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using a filter view so that I can easily switch between different types of filters and I want to exclude certain values from a single column for multiple filter views. The formula below is the one I am having issues with. I am currently using this in the custom formula section of the filter setting which works but includes blank cells. How would I exclude blank/empty cells in this formula?

Works but includes empty cells:

```
=not(regexmatch(D2:D, "Completed and Sent|Killed/On Hold|Completed Post Invoice Change Order"))
```

Does not work:

```
=not(and(regexmatch(D2:D, "Completed and Sent|Killed/On Hold|Completed Post Invoice Change Order"),isblank(D2:D))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=and(not(regexmatch(D2, "Completed and Sent|Killed/On Hold|Completed Post Invoice Change Order")),not(isblank(D2)))
```

You should use NOT() inside AND().Also, just D2 is enough.

Comment: Sweet, tx! I found that I did need a range (eg `D2:D`), though

Comment: @ptim No you don't. `D2` is enough for Apply to: `D2:D`. Only the first cell is required.